# how to save a copy entity JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity of profiles, I make a copy of this entity using SerializationUtils, put down some values ​​and want to save as new record to the database, but for some reason I’m updating the original record from which I made a copy, what I’m doing wrong?

```
Profile profile = profileRepository.findByProfileId(profileId).orElseThrow(() -> {
                            throw new NullPointerException(String.format("profile with  id=%s not found", profileId.toString()));
                        });
Profile newProfile = SerializationUtils.clone(profile);
entityManager.detach(profile);
newProfile.setId(null);
newProfile.setProfileId(UUID.randomUUID());
newProfile.setSnils(profileWithValidationSuccessBySnils.getSnils());                            
entityManager.persist(newProfile);
```

Comment: *Entities which previously referenced the detached entity will continue to reference it.*  as per javadocs, so maybe `detach` earlier or also `detach` `newProfile`?

Comment: ok. How to create a copy of an entity object and save it as a new record in the database?

Comment: Maybe what you are doing is fine, just detach earlier

Comment: it's doesn't work. Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:

Comment: Does `newProfile.setId(null);` actually work?

Comment: it doesn’t affect in any way

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what you're doing with SerializationUtils causes your copy to have the same Hibernate/JPA proxy as the original object, and thus causes Hibernate to treat it AS the original (iow, no different from had you just done "Profile newProfile = profile;"

As I don't know what your SerializationUtils actually does and how it's implemented it's hard to tell but were I to write it I'd take the Hibernate proxy into account in its implementation.

Best way is to just create a new Entity from scratch and feed it the data fields from the original Entity minus the @Id field.

You could do this using a copy constructor for example (I know, it's a dirty word in Java).

That way you are guaranteed to have a completely fresh Entity that's not linked to anything in the persistence store, and thus a new record should always be created.

For one of our projects we wrote what we called the "DeHibernator" for cases like this (and more specifically to strip the Hibernate proxies from objects that needed to be transfered to memory restricted devices where we couldn't load Hibernate just to be able to transmit the proxies and have them work on those devices).

Comment: About the DeHibernator: wouldn't it be the same as calling Hibernate.unproxy() ?

Comment: @Coloco given the structure of the application, it needs to do more than just that, as for each businessobject to be handled there may be more than one Hibernate entity and Hibernate can't always know that those are linked. Ancient application design with Hibernate bolted on top years after the database was created with in many places lacking foreign key relations and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jwenting, I tested with step before and I success:

1. Select entity from DB
2. Convert it to Json (using JsonMapper.toJson)
3. Create new entity from json: JsonMapper.fromJson
4. save new entity
   Lib convert is: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind

Comment: Jackson needs some bloat infrastructure in your POJOs so I think gson in this case is a better alternative